# PowerShell - Export-CSV only listing last of Text File

Tags: text, export-to-csv, windows-scripting

This may be really ridiculous and simple but I am missing something.  I have a very basic script block, but the output is doing something funky.  Code Block is:

```
Get-Content C:\test.txt | ForEach-Object{(Get-ADComputer -Identity $_ -Properties description) | Select-Object name, description `
| Export-Csv -Path 'C:\test.csv' -NoTypeInformation  -Force}
```

The strange thing is that if I comment out the export-csv cmdlet, the code works perfectly by grabbing everything in the text file and lists all the descriptions (as it should). However, when i include it, the Export only lists the very last item on the text file. I have read a few other questions similar to this but no success.  Like I said, I am sure it is something simple but I can't seem to find it.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I found it.. i was missing -append in the export-csv and that worked.